# Replace certain characters with condition PHP

Tags: php, string, format, substring

I'm working on something with PHP. I want to change some characters depending on the condition met. I have a loop which loops thru a series of telephone numbers. The value it can get has two possible format, either `+447532221414` or `447532221414` . What I want to do is just replace the `+44` or `44` to `0`

So I have this checking

```
$sub = substr($row["phone"], 0, 3);
if($sub == "+44")
{
  $phone = str_replace("+44", "0", $row["phone"]);
}
else if(substr($row["phone"], 0, 2) == "44")
{
  $phone = str_replace("44", "0", $row["phone"]);
}
```

But my problem is that when the number is in `447532221414` format it doesn't change the `44` to `0` what could be wrong on the code? Or is there a better approach? Does my logic affect the number which has `44` on the last two digits? For ex. `447532221444`

Comment: All that code can be replaced with `preg_replace('/^\\+?44/', '0', $row['phone'])`. http://regular-expressions.info – Just saying...

Comment: you have to use  php function preg_replace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace`:

```
$phone = "+447532221444";
$phone = preg_replace('/^\+?44/', '0', $phone);

var_dump($phone);
```

What the regex means:

`^` - will force the parser to replace only the matches found at the beginning of the string

`\+?` - will match the `+`, if it exists, but the parser will continue if the `+` is missing

Comment: was about to post the same :) just explain it a bit :P

Comment: Works perfect :) Thank you. Will select this after the timer. :)